# Django filter queryset on "tuples" of values for multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

Say I have a model:

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()
    birthday = models.DateField()
    # etc...
```

and say I have a list of 2 first names: `first_list = ['Bob', 'Rob']` And I have a list of 2 last names: `last_list = ['Williams', 'Williamson']`.  Then if I wanted to select everyone whose first name was in `first_list` I could run:

```
Person.objects.filter(firstname__in=first_list)
```

and if I wanted to select everyone whose last name was in `last_list`, I could do:

```
Person.objects.filter(lastname__in=last_list)
```

So far, so good.  If I want to run both of those restrictions at the same time, that's easy...

```
Person.objects.filter(firstname__in=first_list, lastname__in=last_list)
```

If I wanted to do the `or` style search instead of the `and` style search, I can do that with `Q` objects:

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(firstname__in=first_list) | Q(lastname__in=last_name))
```

But what I have in mind is something a bit more subtle.  What if I just want to return a queryset that returns specific combinations of first and last names?  I.e. I want to return the `Person` objects for which `(Person.firstname, Person.lastname)` is in `zip(first_names, last_names)`.  I.e. I want to get back anyone named the Bob Williams or Rob Williamson (but not anyone named Bob Williamson or Rob Williams).

In my actual use case, `first_list` and `last_list` would both have ~100 elements.

At the moment, I need to solve this problem in a Django app.  But I am also curious about the best way to handle this in a more general SQL context.

Thanks!  (And please let me know if I can clarify anything.)

Comment: There is a nice solution from another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717889/6762200

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't see much solutions except for a big OR clause:

```
import operator
from itertools import izip
query = reduce(
    operator.or_, 
    (Q(firstname=fn, lastname=ln) for fn, ln in izip(first_list, last_list))
    )

Person.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could programatically combine `Q` statements like that!  This seems perfect.  Do you know if this sort of query is efficient, from a SQL point of view?

Comment: The generated SQL will be the same as the one you'd write by hand: `SELECT <fieldnames here...> FROM <tablename> WHERE (fistname="X1" AND lastname="y1") OR (firstname="x2" AND lastname="Y2") OR <etc....>`.  For more efficiency you may want to add an index on (firstname, lastname), on a large dataset with real-life data it _should_ be discriminating enough to speed up things (assuming your db server is smart enough to use it), but first try it as is and check if it really needs any optimisation.

Comment: Oh and if you know of another way to write a SQL query getting the same results please let me know, I'm always willing to learn new things.

Comment: I'm a SQL newbie myself.  The other general approach that came to mind was to dynamically create a merged column in the query itself:  `SELECT <fieldnames> FROM <tablename> WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname) IN <list of concatted first and last names>`.  (EDIT: I think your approach might be faster because a well-designed SQL engine should first filter on the acceptable firstnames OR the acceptable lastnames and then check whether the pairs are ok, while mine would need to make the concatted col for each row).  Curious what others have to add!

Comment: @DJ_8one6: I'm not a SQL guru in any way but my experience with SQL databases is that just like with C compilers if you use a good one and know the right flags / indexes / whatever tricks, you'll have a very hard time getting better optimisation "by hand", so better to write good but simple code and let the db engine / compiler do the job (with just a little hints). My 2 cents...

Answer (score 16):

bruno's answer works, but it feels dirty to me - both on the Python level and on the SQL level (a large concatenation of ORs). In MySQL at least, you can use the following SQL syntax:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (first_name, last_name) IN
       (('John','Doe'),('Jane','Smith'),('Bill','Clinton'))
```

Django's ORM doesn't provide a direct way to do this, so I use raw SQL:

```
User.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM table WHERE (first_name, last_name) IN %s',
      [ (('John','Doe'),('Jane','Smith'),('Bill','Clinton')) ])
```

(This is a list with one element, matching the single %s in the query. The element is an iterable of tuples, so the %s will be converted to an SQL list of tuples).

Notes:

1. As I said, this works for MySQL. I'm not sure what other backends support this syntax.
2. A bug in python-mysql, related to this behavior, was fixed in November 2013 / MySQLdb 1.2.4, so make sure your Python MySQLdb libraries aren't older than that.

Comment: in postgresql at least, Nulls will not work well with this suggestion. And if we change the operator from  IN to using "is not distinct from" -then this operator does not appear to handle arrays/lists.But for things without nulls great.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.5 version :

```
import operator
import functools

query = functools.reduce(
    operator.or_, 
    (Q(firstname=fn, lastname=ln) for fn, ln in zip(first_list, last_list))
    )

Person.objects.filter(query)
```