# Producing a list by summing results of 'values_list' in Django queryset

Tags: python, django

Through a Django queryset call, I'm generating a list of integer tuples:

```
[(0,1),(0,2),(0,4),(5,8),.......]
```

I instead need to generate a list which sums the two elements inside the tuple together, i.e.

```
[1,2,4,13,.....]
```

How can I accomplish that within the Django queryset query?

The query I've written so far is:

```
photos_score_list = Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday).annotate(unique_comments=Count('photocomment__submitted_by', distinct=True)).values_list('vote_score','unique_comments')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Django, but when you have this:

```
l = [(0,1),(0,2),(0,4),(5,8)]
```

you can compute the sum of each element in one line using list comprehension:

```
l2 = [sum(x) for x in l]
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 4, 13]
```

applied to your problem:

```
photos_score_sum = [sum(x) for x in Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday).annotate(unique_comments=Count('photocomment__submitted_by', distinct=True)).values_list('vote_score','unique_comments')]
```

Comment: Interesting, hold on, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: If this elegant solution is not working with Django queryset queries, maybe `functools.reduce` and `operator.add` can help? Cf. with a different problem (IN/or) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177749/django-filter-queryset-on-tuples-of-values-for-multiple-columns

Comment: If it's like the querydict in Django then you may have to call `list()` on it first.

Comment: Not sure if you need that, but you can also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) since `map` in Python 3 return an iterator. So `map(sum, l)`.

Comment: you have to convert to list when you use `map` so listcomps have definitely the upper hand in python 3. I have stopped using `map` & `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have that list of tuples, you can use a list comprehension to generate your second list like below:

```
>>> tuples_list = [(0,1),(0,2),(0,4),(5,8)]
>>> res_list = [i+j for i,j in tuples_list]
>>> res_list
[1, 2, 4, 13]
```

In our list comprehension, we return for tuple `(i,j)` in `tuples_list` the sum `i+j` and the result is sorted in `res_list`.