Django filter objects using two fields
I have a Django model looks like this
class Product(models.Model):
    product_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    product_sub_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...

Where a product can be defined as



name
product_type_id
product_sub_id




toy cars
13
8


toy planes
13
11


cheese
2
1


bread
2
4


chocolate cake
2
8



With a list of (product_type_id, product_sub_id), is there an easy way to filter out products rather than pulling all matched objects and compare them with the list afterwards?
For example I have [(13, 8), (2, 1)] for retrieving product "toy cars" and "cheese"
My current solution is
my_list = [(13, 8), (2, 1)]

filtered_products = Products.objects.filter(
    product_type_id__in = [i[0] for i in my_list],
    product_sub_id__in = [i[1] for i in my_list]
)

# filtered_products contains chocolate cake which I don't want
# so have to do another compare
matching_products = [p for p in filtered_products if (p.product_type_id, product_sub_id) in my_list]


The solution will also include (13, 1) and (8, 2) if these are in the list.

that's what I want to avoid, my current solution will not match those records since I am doing a check at the end, but I can't think of an easier way  @willeM_VanOnsem

For anyone who is interested, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62036179/5302121 works, the flagged answer in the duplicated question does not work in modern python. If you are using mssql like me, don't bother to try the django orm extra function since mssql does not support tuples in the IN clause
